# Is it possible to click a hyperlink in console app?

Tags: c, hyperlink, console-application, mouse

I want to do a program in c which is like browser but i cant create a hyperlink which is clickable.

***Scenario***:
There should be text in console application.Inside the text, there should be hyperlink.Then,i click this and another text should be appeared in console.

**Questions**:

Is it possible to click something in console?

NOTE: I don't know is my operating system is matter but mine is Linux.

Comment: Depends on the console.

Comment: Which console and library should i use?

Comment: A console which detects a URLs it displayed and does something when it gets clicked.

Comment: Some reading here: http://www.linuxplanet.com/linuxplanet/reviews/6964/1 and here: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/

Comment: I read this document. I can handle mouse click in terminal with this lib but i can't handle does my cursor over the hyperlink.